# VS - Android - How to change seekbar style from yellow to original blue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, styles, seekbar

I made the app background transparent and after that the seekbar style changed from original blue holo to yellow (see picture). Android emulator is set to 4.2.2

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>    
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**Main.axml** seekbar style:

```
<SeekBar
    p1:layout_width="250dp"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/seekbarLevel"
    p1:max="100"
    p1:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    p1:layout_gravity="center" />
```

1. How to make seekbar use standard style?
2. Is there a tutorial or something about formatting or styling seekbar and other controls? How to make other shapes and colors?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Halo style back to your `SeekBar`:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar"
```

[image]

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekbarLevel"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"       
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekbarLevel"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"       
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar" />
```

Comment: @SWA As far as "standard" styles : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html As far as the various Halo styles, you can look at the source : https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/b056324630b8adfeb38393bcab49f3b9c720f4fd/core/res/res/values/styles_holo.xml

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn the progress blue, try this in your XML under your seekbar:

```
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/Blue"
    android:progressTint="@color/Blue"
```

And make sure to add this line to your color strings

```
    <color name="Blue">#0000ff</color> //or whatever variation of blue you want
```

Here is the more complete example, including how to change the thumb of the seekbar (little circle)

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/blueSeek"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:colorControlActivated="@color/Blue"
    android:max="4096"
    android:progress="1800"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/Blue"
    android:progressTint="@color/Blue"
    android:thumbOffset="10dp"
    android:thumbTint="@color/Blue"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/redSeek" />
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include more including how to change the thumb of the seekbar to a different color

Comment: What error are you getting when you try and compile? Also what is the minimum api you are targeting?